# Is there any reason to ever use a less secured content security policy(CSP)?

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

I am learning about content-sercurity-policy.

lets say my site abc.com has csp of:

```
default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' xyz.com
```

does this mean that it will use the source of csp from xyz.com?

what if i change it to just:

```
default-src 'self'
```

if the first one is more secure, is there any reason to ever use the simpler one? In other words, wouldn't it always be better to have more secure csp?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' xyz.com`
>
> Does this mean that it will use the source of csp from xyz.com?

`'self'`

Refers to the origin from which the protected document is being served, including the same URL scheme and port number.

`'unsafe-inline'`

Allows the use of inline resources, such as inline `<script>` elements, `javascript:` URLs, inline event handlers, and inline `<style>` elements.

`'unsafe-eval'`

Allows the use of eval() and similar methods for creating code from strings.

`xyz.com`

Allows content from 'xyz.com' host. (See `host-source` under the source)

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/default-src

---

The second CSP is more restrictive then the first. It only allows content hosted from the same origin.

I would recommend having a read of [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) to get a better understanding of the purpose of CSP's and how they can best be used effectively.

Comment: Thank you for the information. After reading the resources, is the reason for making a site's csp less restrictive by allowing adding other site dependencies just so that other sites can make trusted action? Or is there any other reason that I am missing?

Comment: @bZhang  As an example: say you want to include jQuery on your website and you want to use a CDN. You would include the CDN's jQuery URL in your CSP so that it allows the script to run. Without it, the browser would prevent jQuery from being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your second option is more secure, but to allow inline script you can use nonce OR SHA256.

For more information, you can follow the given links.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/#if_you_absolutely_must_use_it

https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/adopting-csp.html#refactor-inline-event-handlers-and-javascript-uris